# Unregister RegId GCM When uninstall app

Tags: android, notifications, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I know have many question like my question. But It is different.
I make a Android app using GCM to push notification. It have problem.

When I install app, I got `regId` of this install. I store it in mysql. Then I push notification and My device receives this notification.

However, After I uninstall app then install again, I got `regId` another and store it in mysql. I push notification to all `regId` I stored in mysql. And now My device receives this notification two times.

Repeat again step above many times. I got many `regId` another and store them into mysql. Then push notification to all `regId` I stored in mysql. Now My device receives the notification by the time I installed app.

I tried unregister `regId` when uninstall app but it can not. Is there any suggestion to unregister `redId` when I uninstall app or do anything solve my problem?

Comment: The way I work around this is giving every notification a unique message id, and one the device, keeping a list of the last ten unique messages it received.  Of course, this is only a work-around to the problem and not a real solution.

Comment: Yes, I've tried your suggestion but as you say this is only a work-around to the problem and not real solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use a ID to verify device with installationId is:

```
UUID.randomUUID().toString()
```

Then send `RegId` and `InstallationID` to the server. When push notification, I push more `InstallationID`.

Answer (score 0):

When you uninstall your application, your registration id, the Token,
will be useless value.

Your sending push acts will not be succeeded with invalid token.

Just using InstanceId for getting token

```
InstanceID instanceID = InstanceID.getInstance(this);
String token = instanceID.getToken("SENDER_ID",
                        GoogleCloudMessaging.INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE, null);
Log.i(TAG, "GCM Registration Token: " + token);
```

Comment: So, what is there method called when i uninstall to execute your code?

Comment: You don't have to add a code into your application for uninstalling.

Comment: When you uninstall your application, The GCM token will be useless automatically by google services. The most important thing is way of getting your registration key. can you show me your getting routine?